# nginx Request Timeout after a few requests, if index.php redirect is present

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, php-7

I'm setting up a PHP7-LEMP-Vagrant box for my new project. I was using Apache before, so i need to translate the rule that redirects all not existing files to index.php. I did this with the following in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

After adding this and restarting nginx, i can access my site once, maybe navigating to another site, but then all following requests will timeout. It's not important which URL i call first, i can call any URL once.

**/var/log/nginx/error.log:**

```
[error] 21885#21885: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.13.1, server: myserver.dev, request: "GET /user/me HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "myserver.dev", referrer: "http://myserver.dev/"
```

**/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf**: Nothing interesting here.

**Website configuration file**:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  myserver.dev;
        root /vagrant/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /var/www/html;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I gave up on this. On my webserver with PHP 5.6 everything was running fine until i activated php5-mcrypt. If php5-mcrypt is enabled, requests timeout.